# Square root of x : $\sqrt{x}$ (Numerical Method)

Tags: numerical-methods

$$f(x) = \sqrt{x}$$
has to be approximated by polynomial interpolation $p(x_n) = f(x_n)$ with the positions $\{x_n\} = \{1,4\}$. For such problem which method is the fastest? And find $p(2)$.

My attempt:

Newton's Method:

$p(x) = x_{n+1} = x_n + \frac{g(x_i)}{g'(x_n)}$

where $g(x) = x^2 - 1$

then we can find the roots of the given number. But I'm not sure if its the fastest way to calculate the square roots.

Thanks.

Comment: Fastest for a computer, or fastest on pencil and paper?

Comment: hhhmm... for both I guess...

Comment: Also (as far as computer methods go), it depends on how big $x$ is, and how precise the answer needs to be

Comment: For pencil/paper, there is the "digit by digit" method given [here](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots)

Comment: @lan The first option

Comment: OK. So you have a derivative bound of $1/2$ on this interval (why?). If you want to compute $\sqrt{x}$ to within $\epsilon$ on all of $[1,4]$ you can choose a mesh where the grid spacing is at most $\frac{\frac{\epsilon}{2}}{\frac{1}{2}}=\epsilon$, precompute $\sqrt{x}$ at the mesh points to within an accuracy of $\epsilon/2$ using something like Newton iteration, and then piecewise linearly interpolate.

Comment: However it looks like in your problem they specifically tell you to use just two grid points, in which case you're taking the interpolating polynomial of $(1,1),(4,2)$ which is just the line between them.

Comment: @lan the real question was for $\{x_n\} = \{0,1,4,9\}$

Comment: OK, well, it's essentially the same, you just have to do some actual work to do the interpolation in that case. Do you know how to do polynomial interpolation?

Comment: Lagrange poly interpolation??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40835/discussion-between-rndflas-and-ian).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You problem asks for $p(x) = \frac{4-x}{4} + \frac{x}{2}$ for which $p(0) = 1 = f(1)$ and $p(4) = 2 = f(4)$. Then $p(2) = \frac{3}{2}$.

Comment: how do we know $p(x) = \frac{4-x}{4} + \frac{x}{2}$ ??

Comment: Your problem specified two nodes, namely $x_0 = 1$ and $x_1 = 4$ and said to apply interpolation. As there is one and only one polynomial of degree 1 which interpolates $f$ on those two nodes and $p$ does the job it must be *the* interpolating polynomial required.

Comment: what would be p(x) if $\{x_n\} = \{0,1,4,9\}$??

Comment: Then you need to apply the general formula for interpolating polynomial of degree at most 3. Either compute Lagrange's form or Newton's form of the interpolating polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

There are available many methods like

1> the Quasi Newton

2> Secant method

3>fixed point iteration method

All of these you can find explained in Justin Solomon's book **Numerical Algorithms**